# Implementation of std::disjunction in the Standard Library

Tags: c++, c++17, standard-library

I've seen the implementation of [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) in the Standard Library ([source](https://gist.github.com/picanumber/3794ec6e80379ff4b727fa01d4819532)):

```
template<class...> struct disjunction : std::false_type { };
template<class B1> struct disjunction<B1> : B1 { };
template<class B1, class... Bn>
struct disjunction<B1, Bn...>
    : std::conditional_t<bool(B1::value), B1, disjunction<Bn...>> { };
```

I am curious about the need to specialize `disjunction<B1>` as `B1`. Why is it better than my naive implementation of it?

```
template<class...>              struct or_t
    : std::false_type {};
template<class B1, class... Bn> struct or_t<B1, Bn...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, bool(B1::value) || bool(or_t<Bn...>::value)> {};
```

Comment: Note that `std::disjunction` short-circuits.

Comment: @Zereges this might be an answer ;)

Comment: This is certainly *not* a standard library implementation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

moreover, `disjunction<B1,...,BN>` is required resulting in the last given type (`BN`) if all of them are falsy (see [[meta.logical#10.2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta.logical#10.2)).

The unary specialization `disjunction<B1>` implements this behaviour in the tail of the recursive sequence.

For example, without the unary specialization, `disjunction<B1>` would give `B1` if `B1::value` is `true`, and `std::false_type` otherwise.

---

> Since all Bs might have different types, std::disjunction returns the first type whose ::value member converts to true. Isn't that a bit strange? It might be useful to make a funny selector

indeed, I've never used this family of traits(yet), but it seems quite a flexible abstraction:

```
template<class T>
struct some_condition: std::bool_constant</*whatever*/>
{
  using payload = T;
};

// take the first T satisfying some_condition, or last T if none does
disjunction<some_condition<T>...>::payload

// take the first T satisfying some_condition, or none
disjunction<some_condition<T>...,none_type>::payload
```

the only thing I hate about *disjunction* is its name ...

Answer (score 6):

You return `std::integral_constant`.

`std::disjunction` returns one of the given type (which might have additional member).

Comment: Since all `B`s might have different types, `std::disjunction<B...>` returns the first type whose `::value` member converts to `true`. Isn't that a bit strange? It might be useful to make a funny selector/(a)buse sfinae...